# delay Without Sleep functions error

Tags: raspbian, python

Sleep without sleep

```bsh
python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

```py
import time
    
last_millis = 0
time_period = 1000 # 1 = 1 millsec , 1000 = 1 sec

def do_somthing():
  print(last_millis)

while True:
  this_millis = int(time.time()*1000.0) # nanosec to millsec

  if this_millis - last_millis >= time_period:
    last_millis = this_millis
    do_somthing()
```

prints every 1 second as expected

```bsh
1648794877918
1648794878918
1648794879918
1648794880918
...
```

Changing `while True:` to a so-called function `def no_sleep():`

```py
import time

    
last_millis = 0
time_period = 1000 # 1 = 1 millsec , 1000 = 1 sec


def do_somthing():
  print(last_millis)

    
def no_sleep():
  this_millis = int(time.time()*1000.0) # nanosec to millsec

  if this_millis - last_millis >= time_period:
    last_millis = this_millis    
    do_somthing()

while True:
  do_somthing()
```

results in error

```bsh
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last_millis' referenced before assignment
```

Any help on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function treats last_millis as a local variable, because last_millis is redefined in no_sleep().

Try adding:

```
global last_millis
```

as the first line of function no_sleep and see what happens.

Comment: The solution to the script was not required.  [my gist](https://gist.github.com/Tearran/60ec4a18a7cfae8907d533e2ed8c8a06) is one way to solve it. 
The understanding why, as you say."Your function treats last_millis as a local variable." Mind elaberating just a little so I can accept as solution.

Comment: It is the way variables are scoped in Python, your last_millis variable declared in the main application is not seen by functions unless you indicate to them that a specific variable is declared in the main body, the global declaration does that with the last_millis variable.  There are better ways to code which avoid this, maybe pass the variable into the Method.  If the variable is updated in a method then return the updated value from the function etc...  Hope this is helpful